# Programa en C para contar lineas, caracteres y palabras de un texto a escribir

Tags: c

soy MUY novato programando, estoy haciendo una actividad que como dice el titulo debo contar Caracteres, palabras y líneas de un texto a escribir.
El programa funciona pero no como necesito que lo haga, por ejemplo si pongo un espacio pero no escribo nada me lo cuenta como palabra, lo mismo con las líneas.

La salida debería ser algo como:

Numero de caracteres: 10

Numero de palabras: 2

Numero de lineas: 2

Tambien el programa debe terminar cuando yo escriba por ejemplo algo como esto "+!&" pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, lo intente pero no funciona, solo pude lograrlo con el "+".

el "+!&" no deberia aparecer en el contador, ni como caracter o palabra.

No se deben usar arrays ni funciones y eso, solo lo "normal", bucles, variables, etc.
Soy muy nuevo en esto, si los errores son muy obvios disculpenme jeje.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    int lineas,palabras,caracteres;
    lineas=1;
    palabras=1;
    caracteres=0;
    printf("PARA FINALIZAR Y OBTENER LOS RESULTADOS ESCRIBA +!& SEGUIDO DE LA TECLA ENTER. \n \n");
    printf("INGRESE SU TEXTO: \n\n");
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if((c!=' ')&&(c!='\n')&&(c!='\t'))
        {
            caracteres++;
        }
        if (c==' ')
        {
            palabras++;
        }
         if(c=='\n')
         {
          palabras++;
          lineas++;
         }
         if (c=='+')
         {
             caracteres--;
             break;
         }
        }
    printf("\n");
    printf("El numero de caracteres es: %d\n",caracteres);

    printf("El numero de palabras es: %d\n",palabras);

    printf("El numero de lineas es: %d\n",lineas);
}
```

Comment: Creo que lo que le falta a su código es guardar en una variable una bandera de estado con la cual saber si, al momentode leer el caracter, esta ubicado en una palabra; en una secuencia de espacios o en la secuencia especial de finlización para que pieda saber si cada espacio realmente está separando una palabra (y no cuente cada espacio de una sucesion de espacios como palabras que no son) y que el solo caracter `+` no le finalice la captura. Es un ejercicio de aprendizaje que usted debe resolver para aprender; por lo que me limito al comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya mencionó eferion me parece que determinar la cantidad de palabras en base a los espacios no es buena idea. Podría haber números o caracteres que no formen parte del alfabeto y los contarías como palabra.

Así que mí propuesta es que el criterio sea en base a caracteres del alfabeto.

Un problema que podría afectar el funcionamiento del programa es que [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) devuelve un `int`. Al guardar el valor en un `char` estás perdiendo información.

Se me ocurrió plantear el algoritmo como una máquina de estados.

- Con una variable `terminador` que aumente si encuentra el caracter correspondiente de la secuencia `+!&` y vuelva a 0 si no es el caso.
- Con una variable `anteriorEsLetra` que indique si el caracter anterior es una letra para contar las palabras.

El código se ve así. Modificalo como sea necesario:

```
int c;
// 1 = +, 2 = !, 3 = &
int terminador = 0;
int anteriorEsLetra = 0;

int lineas = 1;
int palabras = 0;
int caracteres = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    // Detectar secuencia 
    if (terminador == 0 && c == '+')
        terminador = 1;
    else if (terminador == 1 && c == '!')
        terminador = 2;
    else if (terminador == 2 && c == '&')
        terminador = 3;
    else if (terminador == 3 && c == '\n')
        break;
    else
    {
        // No se detectó la secuencia completa 
        terminador = 0;
        caracteres++;
    }

    if (c == '\n')
        lineas++;

    int esLetra = (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ||
        (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
    if (esLetra && !anteriorEsLetra)
        palabras++;
    
    anteriorEsLetra = esLetra;
}
```

Nota: no funciona con letras que no formen parte del alfabeto inglés por simplicidad. Puedes programarlo fácilmente. Solo es cuestión de agregar las condiciones a `esLetra`.

Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##hVPvbpswEP/OUxydFkBktEm@lbYSadwuEkomINJW9YvrOI01YiJDNGltXmjSXmJ9sPQICX/SNbUQHPf7Y/t0x76wmMrHzeaTkCxeTTlcpNlUJM78StOEzGBBhTQt7UkDXHmCudvw9BQ6cAl2G7r40dvQw0@rZGVcLYSk00Rh@swt81QiIhJFUp9nihZgicZCcppislMpljSmD2qbrfkwqihDK57WLJYKoZl58s0LPLgZjjx/eOcF8APG/YiMSAD@OISAhBM/8gYYkvA6GPY9sPUWhOR2MhyMYUDA9yAi1/gmo4gEDtxLfE4st7HHcHSLTgTCCZK/R@Nz5BSsLe3XXMQcTJPh8R55xuZUmZYF@iWQ8Y21pRQlzVcZiBmY9crh1aDVApZHhm1YJTFfjRLvCpYvHqf8P06dykk/5tT90KlbObWOOfU@dOpVTvfywOpBcfqz6VD@PL2/6ZnbwKo@se0KWWuNkr9zgqIbc13FxtbjZeui8AqFnlFc4wLjO8OC5@c9QmvIb8NyG7vufZChH4xF8xz7CajfoAzeDtTOt@CuG037to1JDHK14CoBHP3aUPH0HD5Pkd@uktbBmDW05ZhWyn3qqG438pWqSKBmrW02X5OYIpYlMFtJJhJJndypL7h0tO6/P4XcySdY82neCYwriF/@YhZkAmKxTFRGnVc).

Comment: Ambos codigos me ayudaron a corregir el mio, pero este se ajusta un poco mas a la manera que tengo que hacerlo, muchas gracias tambien por tomarte el tiempo de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo enfocaría de otra forma. Leería la entrada línea a línea y para cada línea, haría un conteo de las palabras y y caracteres.

Es un poco engorroso detectar la secuencia `+!&` si vas caracter a caracter.

Por otro lado hay una serie de consideraciones:

- No creo que debas contabilizar como palabra cada vez que te encuentras un espacio ... ¿Qué pasaría si alguien introduce varios espacios seguidos?
- Si la secuencia finalizadora se encuentra al principio de una línea no creo que debas contar esa línea

El código podría quedar así:

```
// Esta variable será utilizada por getline para saber si debe aumentar
// el tamaño de la reserva de memoria
size_t lineSize = 0;

char * line = NULL;

int caracteres = 0;
int lineas = 0;
int palabras = 0;

int continuar = 1;
while (continuar)
{
    size_t length = getline(&line, &lineSize, stdin);

    // Miramos si esta la secuencia final en esta linea
    char const * pos = strstr(line, "+!&");
    if (pos)
    {
        // Si la secuencia final se encuentra al principio de la linea, no contamos la línea        
        if (pos == line)
            break;
        
        // Hemos encontrado la secuencia final, vamos a dejar de contar justo antes
        length = pos - line;

        // Indicamos que vamos a dejar de pedir líneas
        continuar = 0;
    }
 
    lineas++;

    int en_palabra = 0; // flag para saber si estamos leyendo una palabra

    for (size_t i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] == ' ' || line[i] == '\t' || line[i] == '\n')
        {
            if (en_palabra)
            {
                en_palabra = 0;
                palabras++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            en_palabra = 1;
            caracteres++;
        }
    }

    if (en_palabra)
    {
        palabras++;
    }
}

free(line); // Liberamos la memoria reservada por getline
printf("Palabras: %d\nCaracteres: %d\nLineas: %d\n", palabras, caracteres, lineas);
```

Comment: Gracias por por tomarte el tiempo de hacer este codigo, me servira como referencia para poder hacerlo como lo pide el profesor