# Ingresar texto, y letra. Comparar cada letra inicial de las palabras con la ingresada por el usuario si coincide mostrar en pantalla la palabra

Tags: c++, bucles, comparaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ocupo ingresar un texto, luego ingresar una letra. Comparar la primera letra de cada palabra con la ingresada por el usuario. Luego las palabras que tienen como letra inicial la misma letra ingresada por el usuario mostrarlas en pantalla. No importa si es mayúscula o minúscula, debe ser valido para ambos casos.

Codigo:

```
string Logic::getText(string text, char letter){
    stringstream words; 
    stringstream result;

    for(int i; i < text.size(); i++){
        if(i != text.size() + 1){
                if(text[i] != ' ' and text[i + 1] == ' '){
                    if(text[i]== letter){ //no entra en este if para que agregue la palabra
                        words<<text[i]<<",";
                        
                    }
                    else{//este else es para comprobar que no entra al if anterior
                        std::cout<<"No entre";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    result<<"\nTexto ingresado: "<<text<<"\nLetra ingresada: "<<letter
    <<"\nPalabras que inician con la letra ("<<letter<<"): "<<words.str();

    return result.str();
    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Que el carácter actual no sea un espacio no significa de que estés leyendo una palabra. Considera usar una condición más específica, por ejemplo `letra >= 'a' && letra <= 'z'`. También necesitas distinguir cuando estás leyendo la primera letra de una palabra o no. Supongo que te puede ayudar alguna de las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/557485/169744)